# Build a new Attributes for Product Variant

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-365

My customers want me do a GAP like this on Dynamics 365 F&O:
They want to build a new Attributes, Attribute group for Product Variants. On D365FO only Released Products have attributes, now they want to build it for Product Variants.

I check the data structure of Attributes and Attribute Group, It's very complicated.

You guys thinks this GAP is possible or not?

Please help me, thank you guys!

Comment: Definitely doable, but should be done by someone who has worked in that area before. If you are new to it, it will likely require quite some effort and many test iterations until you get it right.

Comment: Note that the question is rather open ended and rather opinion based. As such, it is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve the question to increase the chances for an answer.